# Regex matches a character, except when next to certain other characters

Tags: regex

I need a regex to match a single quote, but only if the quote is not around a curly brace. These things should match (i.e.):

```
xyz 'bla
12' foo
'abc
''
'%$='
```

But not around curly braces:

```
'{
}'
'{'
'}'
```

I have tried it with negative lookups but it did not work.

```
(?!'{|'})|(?!{'|}')
```

But how I can add the positive phrase?

Comment: The title's a little vague, especially "but not always". You might want to change it to something more precise, like "except when next to certain other characters". See [ask] for tips on that.

Comment: If using pcre type engines could be done like this `'?[{}]'?(*SKIP)(?!)|'` also. https://regex101.com/r/S3aGpH/1

Comment: What does it mean for **a** quote to be **around** something? Do you mean "next to" ?

Answer (score 1):

Put the positive part in the middle, with lookbehind before it and lookahead after it.

```
(?<![{}])'(?![{}])
```

Breakdown:

- `(?<![{}])` - not preceded by a curly brace
- `'`
- `(?![{}])` - not followed by a curly brace

[Try it online on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/1ObweM/1)